# How ensure db<->publish-queue integrity on multi-instance (multiple consumer) micro service

Tags: multithreading, architecture, rabbitmq, microservices

[image]

We have 2 instances of same service deployed, both subscribed to same RABBITMQ queue.
Both receives messages from RABBITMQ, Update data in database and then send data for further processing to UI RABBITMQ queue.
But service which saved last (Instance A) will put data into RABBITMQ sooner,
So user on UI will see Data=2, but in database state is Data=1.
Obviously result on UI should be Data=1.

This is just general question, what are architecture possible solutions in case you wanna hold multipleinstances.

Single instance is not an option here, as we need to process messages faster multiple instances are required.